# How to get p_values of features in survreg?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I working on survival analysis and each time I use a different test set and at the end I would like to have the avg of coefficients, p for each feature and p value of the model. I can get coefficients using srFit$coefficients. But I don't know how to get the p values, although I can see them using summary(srFit).

```
summary(srFit)

Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(time) ~ f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 + f5 + f6 + f7 + f8 + f9 + f10, data = train, dist = dist_pred[i_dist])
                            Value Std. Error       z        p
(Intercept)              1.59e+03   632.0632  2.5092 1.21e-02
f1                      -2.07e+00     1.2283 -1.6881 9.14e-02
f2                       1.03e+00     1.8070  0.5677 5.70e-01
f3                      -7.61e-02     1.3764 -0.0553 9.56e-01
f4                      -3.24e+00     1.4836 -2.1843 2.89e-02
f5                       4.37e-01     0.0961  4.5474 5.43e-06
f6                      -1.36e+00     0.7555 -1.8011 7.17e-02
f7                      -6.26e-03     0.0081 -0.7719 4.40e-01
f8                       3.92e-03     0.0186  0.2111 8.33e-01
f9                      -4.82e-01     0.4291 -1.1235 2.61e-01
f10                     -7.79e-01     0.3139 -2.4809 1.31e-02
Log(scale)               2.73e+00     0.0314 86.9447 0.00e+00

Scale= 15.4 

Student-t distribution: parmameters= 4
Loglik(model)= -4542.1   Loglik(intercept only)= -4570.1
    Chisq= 56 on 10 degrees of freedom, p= 2.1e-08 
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 5 
n= 1008
```

Comment: `summary(srFitt)$table` to see the coefficient table.          you can subset this to get the p.values. More generally to look at the object you can use `str` ... `str(summary(srFit))`

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the statistic names of Summary object using `names(summary(srFit))`, then extract the statistic you want:
`summary(srFit)$statistic_name_here`.
If the statistic you want is a table like in your case, you can extract it into a `data.frame` for eg. 
`df=data.frame(summary(srFit)$statistic_name_here)`
`df$your_column_name` will give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I also want to see p of the model ( p= 2.1e-08 ). But I'm not able to see it. Do you know how I can get it?

Comment: Erin, that p.value is not returned, so you will not see it by using either `st`r or `names`. It is produced in the `print.summary` method. To see how it is produced look at the code of `survival:::print.summary.survreg`. So there us enough info returned in the `summary` object for you to calculate it yourself... ie `1-pchisq(56, 10)` (you can of course, automate the extraction of these values: `s <- summary(srFit) ; 1 - pchisq(s$chi, (s$df-s$idf))`)

Comment: Need to add lower.tail = FALSE like:   `s <- summary(srFit) ; 1 - pchisq(s$chi, (s$df-s$idf), lower.tail = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the p-values from the table in the summary

```
s = summary(srFit)
s$table
s$table[,4]
```